# Pullback-stability of internally projective objects

Tags: ct.category-theory, axiom-of-choice, topos-theory, internalization

An object $X$ of a category $C$ is said to be *projective* if the hom-functor $C(X,-)$ preserves epimorphisms (or, in general, some restricted class of epimorphisms such as the regular or effective ones).  The axiom of choice is equivalent to the assertion that all objects of **Set** are projective.  In general, a "projective set" $X$ is one such that we can make $X$-indexed families of choices.

In section D4.5 of *Sketches of an Elephant*, an object $X$ of a topos $C$ is said to be *[internally projective](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internally+projective+object)* if the right adjoint $\Pi_X : C/X \to C$ preserves epimorphisms, and $C$ is said to satisfy the *internal axiom of choice* if all objects are internally projective.  The latter definition is found in many other places; I haven't seen the former elsewhere, but I don't know its actual origin.

My question is, if $X$ is internally projective in this sense in $C$, is $X\times Y$ internally projective in $C/Y$ for another object $Y$?  This seems to be a necessary condition for the definition to be sufficiently "internal", but I haven't been able to prove it yet.

A similar question is, if $C$ satisfies the internal axiom of choice, does the functor $\Pi_f : C/X \to C/Y$ preserve epimorphisms for any morphism $f:X\to Y$?

Comment: Your 'similar question' looks very much like a hypothetical definition for internal projectivity of a map, and something that algebraic geometers might have studied.

Comment: It's exactly internal projectivity of $f$ as an object of $C/Y$, so the question is equivalent to: if $C$ satisfies the internal axiom of choice, does every slice category also do so?

Comment: If I recall correctly MacLane and Moerdijk define "$X$ is internally projective" as "${-}^X$ preserves epis", so that is like a non-dependent version of your definition. Does that make a difference? Probably not in a topos.

Comment: Mike - I know :-) I read your post at the nForum. @AndrejBauer - I'm guessing Mike doesn't just want to assume $C$ is a topos, since his stack semantics paper deals in the ambient setting of a pretopos.

Comment: For purposes of this question, I'm happy to assume $C$ is a topos.  In this case at least, the Elephant proves that the two definitions of internal projectivity are equivalent.  But I don't immediately see how that could help.

Comment: For toposes, I believe there is a follow-your-nose argument that if both $X,Y$ are internally projective in $\mathbb{C}$ then $X \times Y$ is internally projective in $\mathbb{C}/Y$. (I have only had time to rush-check the argument.) If so, this shows that the internal axiom of choice is preserved under slicing; and also a similar approach should give a positive answer to the "similar question" at the end of your question. As to your original preservation question, I suspect it is false. Nonetheless, I don't myself find the terminology "internally projective" inappropriate.

Comment: I retract the sentence beginning "If so" in my previous comment. The simple observation of the first sentence is not enough to get preservation of IAC (internal axiom of choice). On the other hand, it seems to me that, even if the answer to your first question is in general negative, it may nonetheless still be the case that IAC is always preserved by slicing.

Comment: The reason I would expect an "internal" statement to be preserved by slicing is that if you extend the Kripke-Joyal semantics for internal logic to quantifiers over all objects (arXiv:1004.3802), or embed the topos in a category of sheaves or ideals as in algebraic set theory, then the resulting interpretation of any statement *will* be stable under pullback/slicing, just like ordinary statements in the internal logic.  So a statement which is not so stable cannot be expresed "internally" in such a way.

Comment: @Mike. Re terminology, I had understood your reasons but had conflicting ones. Fortunately there is no need to argue, since the preservation property does hold. I now retract my first comment entirely. It was misguided.

Comment: This is also Exercise 16(b) in Chapter IV of Mac Lane and Moerdijk.  (16(a) shows that the definition given here matches the definition used in the book.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For toposes, the stability property of your first question does hold. Suppose $X$ is internally projective in $\mathbb{C}$. And suppose $q: B \to A$ is an epimorphism from $v : B \to I$ to $u: A \to I$ in $\mathbb{C}/I$, hence an epimorphism in $\mathbb{C}$. Write $X^*$ for the object $X \times I$ of $\mathbb{C}/I$. The exponential $u^{X^*}$ in $\mathbb{C}/I$ has underlying object:
$$ \{(i,f) : I \times A^X \mid \forall x:X.\, u(f(x))=i\}$$
And the map $q^{X^*}$ is a pullback in $\mathbb{C}$ of the map 
$$I \times q^X: I \times B^X \to I \times A^X$$ along the embedding of  $u^{X^*}$ in $I \times A^X$. Since the displayed map above is an epi by  internal projectivity of $X$, so is its pullback $q^{X^*}$.

It is also true that the internal axiom of choice (IAC) is preserved by slicing. (I haven't managed to see that this follows as a direct consequence of the previous.) Suppose IAC holds in a topos $\mathbb{C}$. Consider an arbitrary object $w: Z \to I$ in $\mathbb{C}/I$, and an epimorphism $q$ as above. The exponential $u^w$ in $\mathbb{C}/I$ has underlying object
$$\{(i,f): I \times (1+A)^Z \mid \forall z:Z.\, (w(z)= i \to \exists a:A. f(z) = \text{inr}(a) \wedge u(a) = i) \wedge (w(z) \neq i \to f(z) = \text{inl}(*)) \}$$
This uses a standard representation of slice-category exponentials in toposes in terms of partial map classifiers, with the simplification that, since $\mathbb{C}$ is boolean (using Diaconescu's theorem that IAC implies boolean), the partial map classifier for $A$ is $1 + A$. Similar to the previous argument, one now observes that $q^w$ is a pullback in $\mathbb{C}$ of the map
$$I \times (1+q)^Z : I \times (1+B)^Z \to I \times (1+A)^Z$$
along the subobject inclusion of $u^w$. And once again the map displayed above is an epi, by internal projectivity of $Z$.

Comment: Very nice, thank you!  Does the second argument actually depend on Booleanness?  It seems that it ought to work just as well with $1+A$ replaced by whatever the partial map classifier happens to be.  If so, then it would imply that $w:Z\to I$ is internally projective in $\mathbb{C}/I$ whenever $Z$ is internally projective in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I couldn't see that the partial-map-classifier functor preserves epis in general. I used booleanness to get around this.